# Convert nominal to numeric data?

Tags: dataset, cluster-analysis, numeric

I am trying to run clustering algorithm on my dataset. My dataset are set of packets(source Ip, destination, port , class label). I want to convert these data from nominal to numeric data. What are the proper techniques to convert these data?

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach is to perform *one hot encoding*. While this obviously encodes the data numerically, it comes with several problems.

1. Increased dimensionality. This often causes scalability and discrimination problems (distances between points become too similar)
2. Normalization and weighting problems. Typical normalization strategies such as min-max scaling and standardization don't work as desired'
3. Correlated attributes
4. handling of new attribute values
5. The variables will be discrete. Many algorithms such as k-means require *continuous* attributes to work well.
6. Interpretation problems. E.g. a cluster center will often not map back in a meaningful way to the original space.